# XQuartz does not work correctly

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ssh, x11, xquartz

I have got a problem with XQuartz. We are running a server on which we installed an application which runs via Wine. If I start the application via Linux it works perfect.

But with my Macbook (OS X Sierra 10.12.5) it does not start.
I connect to the server with ssh -X serverID, after this I try to start the application with ./"appname" and it happens just nothing.
In the background XQuartz has already started while I was connecting to the server, but then it does not do anything. No error messages, nothing. Just a little freeze.
If I try to open xeyes, this app starts but without the animation of the Iris. Someone who can help me?

Comment: Are you starting this from Terminal or from an xterm window, from within XQuartz? I find that sometimes you have to start x11 processes from xterm.

Comment: It does not care actually. Neither terminal nor xterm works and same problems. If I want to start xeyes on xterm it works perfectly. After I connect to server via ssh -X nothing works.

Comment: Connect with -Y instead

Comment: No does not work also.
I tried to debug that even xcalc is not opened and there is nothing suspicious:

user@server:~$ xcalc:
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from ::1 54364
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11

Answer (score 1):

Please try by providing /full_path/appname on the Terminal, Where full_path is the path which the particular appname is located.

Comment: Does not work. Now my Terminal does not freeze anymore, but the application still does not start.

Comment: Is there any messages appearing on the terminal after running application.Please check Xquartz -> preferences ,may be after changing some color settings it will work. For me i was having an Xquartz app that will work only with 256 color mode.

Comment: No messages appearing. I type ./"scriptname" and it does just nothing. Also this does not work. Still, before connecting I test just "xeyes" or "xclock" and it works. After I connect to the server it does not work. The application does not work, too.